# visjs physics - keep the node when it was dropped

Tags: vis.js

When dragging a node, I would like to leave the node **and its connected nodes** exactly where I dropped them.
In the example bellow, you can see that when dropping the node/s they keep going back to the original place.

https://jsfiddle.net/5fz13ve2/4/

```
 physics: {
        repulsion: {
            centralGravity: 1,
            springConstant: 0.05,
        },
        stabilization: true
    },
    interaction: {
        tooltipDelay: 200,
        hideEdgesOnDrag: false
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Turn off physics (`physics: false`). Stabilize will still work as will initial layout, it will even respect your options.

Alternatively you can set the moved nodes fixed to keep physics on for the other nodes. However you'd have to handle this manually (fixed nodes can't be moved at all so you'd have to change fixed to true/false dynamically).

Comment: physics: false is not an option.  Please red the bolded first row again. `I would like to leave the node and its connected nodes exactly where I dropped them` I want to drop the nodes... also see my example please

Comment: Well, you can apply fixed for nodes recursively to the entire subgraph if you want. I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. It seems that you don't want physics but want it at the same time? Could you provide more details? Maybe a working MWE (the one you provided dies with Uncaught ReferenceError: vis is not defined) and highlight which nodes you want to drag and which shouldn't move afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. have a look im this example, drag and release the red node: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-lake-jyn8q?file=/index.js:1043-1061

Comment: If this is supposed to be an example of something else that works that way, it seems to me that their edges aren't flexing, like ours, but are infinitely stretching. I'm afraid you can't replicate this in Vis Network, the physics just doesn't work this way.

Comment: So in vis.js as long as i have physics, it will always want to go back to the center? thanks